# How to send event parameters for a tag through the google tag manager API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

With this query i can create a GTM event tag for Google Analytics 4. i would like to pass some event parameters aswell. I feel that im really close because the API seems to recognize the eventParameters key, it tells me that its value its invalid.

`"vendorTemplate.parameter.eventParameters[0]: The value is invalid.\n",`

If i change this eventParameters key to something else, the query goes through (obviously without taking into consideration my eventParameters) so i know that this code has to be close.

The documentation is really shallow so building queries with the GTM api its been very trial and error until now.

When i get this working i'll probably make a sample for automating trigger and tag creation for GA4 migrations

`

```
{
  "name": "test2",
  "type": "gaawe",
  "parameter": [
    {
      "type": "template",
      "key": "eventName",
      "value": "hey"
    },
    {
      "type": "tagReference",
      "value": "LocalTag",
      "key": "measurementId"
    },
    {
      "type": "list",
      "key": "eventParameters",
      "list": [
        {
          "type": "template",
          "value": "page_title",
          "key": "page_title"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters is a array

Here is the example:

```js
    {
      "type": "MAP",
      "map": [
        {
          "type": "TEMPLATE",
          "key": "name",
          "value": `${parameterName}`
        },
        {
          "type": "TEMPLATE",
          "key": "value",
          "value": `${parameterValue}`
        }
      ]
    }
```

And if you want to pass a variable to the value
Just add the "{{" , "}}" as you used in GTM UI.

Like {{DataLayer-Ecommerce}}

So yes you are very close to it.